# In LO Writer, how to set Ctrl+6 as keyboard shortcut for the Heading 6 style?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, styles

There are shortcuts for headings 1 to 5 styles, but I find no option in the "Customize" dialog to set a keyboard shortcut for the Heading 6 and higher styles.  How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard
2. On the Shortcut Keys list, find Ctrl+6.
3. On Category list, select Styles -> Paragraph.
4. On the Function List, select Heading 6.
5. Click Modify. Click OK

[image: LibreOffice Writer - Customize window]

Comment: So it was buried under Styles → Paragraph.  I searched for "Heading" in the Functions text box, but nothing turned up.  Go figure.  Anyway, thank you!